# How can I mute audio YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI?

Tags: android, audio, youtube, youtube-api

I want to mute volume of YouTube Android Player API I have used YouTubePlayerFragment and while i put custom ImageView on it it shows me error `

> YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI

: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player.` So how i can put button to mute audio Is there any one who can help me?

```
youTubePlayerSupportFragment.initialize(API_KEY, new com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationSuccess(final com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                        mTubePlayer = youTubePlayer;
                        mTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
                        mTubePlayer.setManageAudioFocus(true);
                        if (ytInit.size() - 1 > linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition())
                            mTubePlayer.cueVideo(strings.get(linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()), ytInit.get(linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()));
                        else
                            mTubePlayer.cueVideo(strings.get(linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()));
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (mTubePlayer != null) {
                                    showEpisodeThumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    prg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    mTubePlayer.play();
                                    frm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                            }
                        }, 1000);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationFailure(com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: read the question and let me know where is answer poster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer youtube doesn't provide any facility to mute audio in API I have used custom iframe player